# counting entries yields a wrong dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

So I'm trying to automate the process of getting the number of entries a person has by using pandas.

Here's my code:

```
st = pd.read_csv('list.csv', na_values=['-'])
auto = pd.read_csv('data.csv', na_values=['-'])
comp = st.Component.unique()
eventname = st.EventName.unique()

def get_summary(ID):
    for com in comp:
        for event in eventname:
            arr = []
            for ids in ID:
                x = len(st.loc[(st.User == str(ids)) & (st.Component == str(com)) & (st.EventName == str(event))])
                arr.append(x)

            auto.loc[:, event] = pd.Series(arr, index=auto.index)
```

The output I get looks like this:

[image]

I ran some manual loops to see the entries for the first four columns. And I counted them manually too in the csv file. But when I put a `print` function inside the loop, I can see that it does count the entries correctly, but at some point it gets overwritten with the zero values.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to check how many times a User has been listed?

Comment: Not sure what your original df looks like but why can't you do a crosstab?